# Put to sleep all monitors except one when on idle

Tags: windows-10

In Windows `Power Options` it is possible to configure `Turn off display after` some time of inactivity. But in a multimonitor environment this settings affects all monitors at once. Is there any way to configure this setting per monitor? Especially I want to disable stand by for the one of my displays and keep it working for the others.
The reason for this is that my motherboard does not have SPDIF output port, and I connect a high quality acoustics using optical cable through HDMI audio extractor. But when I am not using my PC - music stops playing when monitors are turned off by Windows.
May be there is an option to turn off monitor but keep sound working over HDMI?

Comment: Probably easier to just buy a 10-buck external audio DAC & let HDMI do its thing.

Comment: You can set a blank screen saver with the same time of inactivity instead of using the power option. The monitors will be black but won't be off so audio should continue to play. It may not be the same as turning the displays off but if this workaround satisfies your requirements then you won't need any additional hardware or software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not have such a selective sleep option, so you need
to do it yourself.

To make a monitor sleep you could use the free command-line utility
[MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html).

You may then create two scripts: One that will put the extra monitors
to sleep, and a second that will wake them up.

Use the first script in a scheduled task triggered by the idle state.
For the second one, you may create a desktop icon for quick awakening.

See the post
[Task Scheduler Idle task not triggered on the correct time window](https://superuser.com/questions/1568909/task-scheduler-idle-task-not-triggered-on-the-correct-time-window)
for an example and more information.